# What changed in the Cassandra-Spark integration connector package?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am not able to import  *com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil*, a class which  some documentation mentions e.g. [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/accessing-cassandra-from-spark-in-java).

But I am able to import *com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil*. I'd like to understand the mismatch. Was the *japi* package added? Removed? I am apparently using a newer version than that DataSparx documentation. (I am using v. 1.1.0-rc, and that page mentions 0.9.)

Could someone explain what happened in the recent version history of the DataStax Cassandra-Spark connector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the specific commit diff in your case:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/commit/36ad9cd6c13600144e3e27533587db926e41af2e

And this is the related issue:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/issues/300

Hope it helps.